# What code do I use to create the first prime numbers within 1-50 in SAS?

Tags: sas, primes

I am trying to show only the prime numbers from 1-50

I have already tried using DO loops and MOD functions to show all the numbers which have no remainder but don't know how to remove the rest the non-primes

```
data prime;
  do i=1 to 50;
     j=1 to 50;
     if mod(i,j)=0 then;
     output;
  end;
run;
```

I expected the result I got but am not sure where to go next.

Answer (score 2):

Typical sieve, track primes in an array and check for any prime divisors up to square root of candidate.

```
data primes(keep=candidate rename=candidate=number);
  array primes[50] _temporary_;
  index = 1;
  candidate = 2;
  primes(index) = candidate;
  output;
  do candidate = 3 to 50 by 2;
    checkLimit = sqrt(candidate);
    prime = 1;
    do checkIndex = 2 to index while (prime) ;
      if primes(checkIndex) > checkLimit then leave;
      prime = mod(candidate, primes(checkIndex)) ne 0;
      if not prime then leave;
    end;
    if prime then do;
      index + 1;
      primes(index) = candidate;
      output;
    end;
  end; 
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more efficient ways to find a prime number, but here is how to get your approach to work:

```
data prime;
  do i = 2 to 50;
    prime = 1;
    do j = 2 to i-1;
      if mod(i,j) = 0 then do;
        prime = 0;      
        leave;
      end;
    end;
    if prime then output;
  end;
run;
```

You basically set a flag to say i is not a prime number is it is divisible by a number smaller than i. Once you have iterated through the inner loop, you check the flag to see if it is a prime or not and if it is, you output it.

Leave statement will exit the inner loop immediately after it is found to be divisible by some number

Comment: why i~=j when j is guaranteed to be at least one smaller then i?